# Multi-value editor for path environment variable not showing in Windows 11

Tags: environment-variables, windows-11

For some reason the multi-value editor for my Path environmental variable has stopped showing.  So instead of seeing this editor:
[Multi-value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnQAI.png)

I am now seeing the the single line editor which is rather frustrating, since it makes editing the path variable that much more cumbersome
[Single-value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C6cX.png)

Note that this is on Windows 11

I tried checking the registry but couldn't find any relative setting there. I've also checked that the Path variable value is correct and does not contain any funny characters.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The problem is now fixed.  

The resolution for me was uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio due to an unrelated problem.  My guess is that when Visual Studio updated the path variable for it's own purposes it reset whatever flag Windows uses to know which editor to open

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a bug that occurs when the first value in the path variable starts with a % to expand another variable. The solution is to make sure there is an absolute directory path as first part of the path variable. I just added `C:\;` in the beginning and it activated the multi-value editor again.

Comment: This was my issue. What a crazy bug